# Why am I getting Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 11.0.9.1 error?

Tags: java

I have two versions of Java on my system, one is Java 11 for competitive programming, and Java 8 for developing Cordova apps. I added the `JAVA_HOME` variable by editing `.bashrc` file as:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
```

I also changed the `PATH` variable using

```
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

and I also checked for `PATH` variable

```
echo $PATH
/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v15.5.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/local/android/sdktools/:/local/android/sdkplatform-tools:/home/ubuntu/local/android/sdktools/:/home/ubuntu/local/android/sdkplatform-tools:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin
```

As you can see, Java 8 is available in `PATH`.
`whereis` command returns

```
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
```

When I tried to build a Cordova app, I get following error:

> Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 11.0.9.1

Comment: @Gagan Singh, try to be updated there is another version of JDK came out that is JDK 15 so you should use that.

Comment: You added your Java installation to the *end* of your PATH. And when you just execute `java` then the *first* matching executable will be run. Replace your PATH-setting with `export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH` to prioritize your new Java installation

Comment: @JoachimSauer It works. If you can write this as answer I will accept as correct answer, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added your Java installation to the end of your PATH. When you just execute `java` then the *first* matching executable will be run, which will be your previous already-installed Java installations.

Replace your PATH-setting with this one to prioritize your new Java installation:

```
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use multiple versions of JAVA on a system?

Yes, it is possible

You may check installed java versions in Ubuntu by:

```
$ update-java-alternatives -l
```

I'm afraid you forgot to run `$ source .bashrc` after setting `JAVA_HOME` in .bashrc file.